# Find an optimal shape analytically

Tags: simulations, differential-equations

This is better described with an example: Imagine we posses our current understanding of physics, but we do not know how to make an airplane because we do not know about airfoils. To make this more colorful, say Aliens came from space in the 1800's and gave us knowledge of physics up to subatomic particles. Using these laws, we have to create a shape that creates lift; a.k.a. an airfoil.

Question: Can this be done analytically? by that I mean NOT creating a shape and then using the rules to compute whether air creates lift for that particular shape(this is trial-error and the principle behind wind turbines), BUT finding the optimal shape in a finite number of computational steps.

I am aware this is most likely impossible. but I would like some formalism on why trial-and-error are the best we got

Comment: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/map.html, but I dont know if you could use this to find the optimal solution

Comment: Just about any shape can create lift. You haven't specified what you mean by "optimal."

Comment: @D.Halsey say optimal = if you modify the shape in any way, the overall result will be less lift. Even if a change might mean more lift under very specific conditions, if it reduces the average lift for all speeds, then it's not optimal. Also, the question is not really about lift, but whether we can use analysis to compute shapes that behave in ways we want under the known laws of physics.

Comment: @brucesmitherson lift is just an example. It seems our best hope to design pretty much anything, from cars to rockets, is trial-and-error. All we can know is the laws and how they will make the system behave over time, like in the 3 body problem. I want to know if there is a formalism of this matter, like a proof that the 3-body problem cannot be solved. Maybe I should have posted on math exchange

Comment: Something like this: https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/6.1969-739